# Export xls for a backend module in typo3

Tags: module, backend, typo3-7.6.x

How can we implement export xls click button for a typo3 extbase backend module? My requirement is to fetch data from the database and export that datas as excel file.  Is there any documentation for the export feature?

Answer (score 1):

The export (t3d) is a TYPO3 specific format. but aside of it you can download your data in CSV format:
go to the WEB-> List Module, select your page, start the single-table view by a click on the table name or the adjacent `>` (which has title-attribute: 'List only this table').

In the following view, beyond the records, you can select the visible fields.
at the top yo u have two download buttons: "Download CSV file" and "Export". With "Export" you start the usual t3d export. with "Downlad CSV file" you can download the visible fields of all records as a CSV file. That would be the nearest you can get to a complete Excel file with TYPO3 core.

If you need more you need to program it or use other tools like phpMyAdmin.